# What is the difference between Lodash toString() and JavaScript's native toString() method?

Tags: javascript, lodash

More specifically, I'm referring to [this method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toString) from Lodash and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) JavaScript method.

When would you choose to use one over the other?

Comment: if you click the source link in the link you provided in the question, you will be able to review the code and know how lodash implements their `toString` method.

Comment: Lodash you get 17,000 lines of code - native JavaScript you get zero, but are required to type check what you are `.toString()` ing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my limited test below, Lodash handles `null` & `undefined` by returning an empty string. It also contradicts the ECMAScript standard by returning `-0` for `-0` where the native method returns `0`. (see: [6.1.6.1.20](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring))

You can check out the source for lodash here for implementation details: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/toString.js

The native toString behavior is defined by tc39's [ECMAScript 2021 Language Specification 7.1.17](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring)

[image]

The tests are not exhaustive so feel free to add your own.

```js
console.log("native: " + [1,2,3].toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString([1,2,3]));
console.log("native: " + [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]].toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]));
console.log("native: " + (-0).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(-0));
console.log("native: " + (-0.0).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(-0.0));
console.log("native: " + (Infinity).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(Infinity));
console.log("native: " + (-Infinity).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(-Infinity));
console.log("native: " + (NaN).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(NaN));
console.log("native: " + ({foo:'bar'}).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString({foo: 'bar'}));
console.log("native: " + [{foo:'bar'},{foo:'bar'},{foo:'bar'}].toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString([{foo:'bar'},{foo:'bar'},{foo:'bar'}]));
console.log("native: " + Object.prototype.toString.call(null));
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(null));
console.log("native: " + Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined));
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(undefined));
console.log("native: " + document.toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(document));
console.log("native: " + (new Set()).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(new Set()));
console.log("native: " + Symbol('foo').toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(Symbol('foo')));
console.log("native: " + 'foo'.toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString('foo'));
console.log("native: " + (true).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(true));
console.log("native: " + (BigInt(100000000000000000000)).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(BigInt(100000000000000000000)));
console.log("native: " + (new Date()).toString());
console.log("lodash: " + _.toString(new Date()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So would you say it's safer and therefore better to use lodash's toString() instead of .toString() or JSON.stringify() when converting a value that could be multiple types to string?

Comment: I think either is equally fine to use as long as you understand the behavior of the conversion and handle the workflows appropriatly. Since lodash returns an empty string for `null` and `undefined` it may be easier to code for, but you'd need to make that determination.